# Ubuntu 14.04 - apt get errors

Tags: apt, dpkg, bzip2

need some help.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and when I ran sudo apt-get install -f I get the following errors - kindly assist.

```
Unpacking linux-image-3.13.0-57-generic (3.13.0-57.95) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: internal bzip2 read error: ';DATA_ERROR';
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-57-generic_3.13.0-57.95_i386.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for ';./boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-57-generic'; to ';/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-57-generic.dpkg-new';: unexpected end of file or stream
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-57-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-57-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-57-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-57-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-57-generic_3.13.0-57.95_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is something wrong happening when `dpkg` package management tool calls `tar` program (which uses `bzip2` program in this case) to unpack the files. You could try clearing out the local repository of retrieved package files and then do an update and upgrade. So run:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```